# Using an expression as a join

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, join

I have a query that I'm trying to use in an admin grid. It is summing the values in another table, in a subselect, and then joining on that table:

```
SELECT 
   main_table.*,
   author_debit_amount
FROM   sales_flat_order_item AS main_table
   INNER JOIN sales_flat_order AS order_table
           ON main_table.order_id = order_table.entity_id
   INNER JOIN admin_user AS author
           ON main_table.author_id = author.user_id
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT author_id, SUM(amount) AS author_debit_amount FROM author_debits
               GROUP BY author_debits.author_id) a 
           ON main_table.author_id = a.author_id
WHERE  ( order_table.created_at >= '2014-08-01 04:00:00' ) 
     AND ( order_table.created_at <= '2014-09-01 03:59:59' )
GROUP  BY main_table.author_id;
```

My question is, is it possible to write this query using standard magento collections? i.e., $collection->join(...). The subselect is where I'm stuck:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT author_id, SUM(amount) AS author_debit_amount FROM author_debits
               GROUP BY author_debits.author_id) a 
           ON main_table.author_id = a.author_id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By digging into Zend_Db_Select, I was able to figure it out:

```
$query = 'SELECT author_id, SUM(amount) AS author_debit_amount FROM author_debits GROUP BY author_debits.author_id';
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$query.')'),
    'main_table.author_id = t.author_id',
    array('author_debit_amount')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Step1:**primary item collection of order item:**

```
  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
```

Step2: sales_flat_order table inner join by below code

```
 $collection ->joinInner(
                array('order_table' =>'sales_flat_order'),
                'main_table.order_id = order_table.entity_id',
                array());
```

Step3: admin_user table inner join by below code

```
$collection ->joinInner(
                array('author' =>'admin_user'),
                'main_table.author_id = author.user_id',
                array());
```

Step4:**author_debit_amount table left join**

> $collection ->getSelect()         ->joinLeft(          array('a' =>
>   'author_debits'),         ' main_table.author_id = a.author_id'
>                   ->columns('SUM(a.amount) as author_debit_amount ,a.author_id')
>                   ->group('a.author_id');

Comment: That would do the sum in the select rather than using the sum as a join. But, I may use this elsewhere in my project. Thanks!